# Nodejs tutorial: User Signup

Tags: node.js, mongoose, schema, passport.js

I am practicing a nodejs mongoose passport tutorial from here: http://www.scotchmedia.com/tutorials/express/authentication/2/03. It is a multi-part tutorial, and I've been stuck in one of the steps for 3 days now. I suspect that there is a missing statement in the code but not really sure and I could not make contact with the author.

I comment it at the line with a string of question marks, ?????????????? Could you take a look. Thanks in advance.

```
var emailSchema = new Schema({
    // Since `type` is special keyword in mongoose we must set the def. to
    // and object. I.e. this would not work:
    // type: String,
    type  : {type: String},
    value : String
});

// define the userSchema
var userSchema = new Schema({
    name : {
        givenName   : String,
        familyName  : String
    },
    emails: [emailSchema],
    passwordHash: String
});


exports.signup = function (req, res) {
    req.onValidationError(function (msg) {
        //Redirect to `/signup` if validation fails
        return res.redirect('/signup');
    });
    req.check('email', 'Please enter a valid email').len(1).isEmail();
    req.check('password', 'Please enter a password with a length between 4 and 34 digits').len(4, 34);
    req.check('givenName', 'Please enter your first name').len(1);
    req.check('familyName', 'Please enter your last name').len(1);
    // If the form is valid craete a new user
    var newUser = {
        name: {
            givenName: req.body.givenName,
            familyName: req.body.familyName
        },
        emails: [
            {
                value: req.body.email
            }
        ]
        // Is something (like passwordHash) missing here ??????????????
    };

    // hash password
    User.hashPassword(req.body.password, function (err, passwordHash) {
        // update attributes
        newUser.passwordHash = passwordHash;
        // Create new user
        User.create(newUser, function (err, user) {
            return res.redirect('/account');
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

```
newUser.passwordHash = passwordHash;
```

The password hash is set already.

So nothing is missing there

Comment: I note that you are from Vietnam. I am Vietnamese too, from US. May I get in touch with you over email? Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Sure, reach me at dungcaond@gmail.com